# Why does a right shift on a signed integer causes an overflow?

Tags: bit-manipulation, hla

Given any 8 bits negative integer (signed so between -1 and -128), a right shift in HLA  causes an overflow and I don't understand why. If shifted once, it should basically divide the value by 2. This is true for positive numbers but obviously not for negative. Why? So for example if -10 is entered the result is +123.

```
       Program cpy;

       #include ("stdlib.hhf")
       #include ("hla.hhf")


     static
     i:int8;


    begin cpy;
    stdout.put("Enter value to divide by 2: ");
    stdin.geti8();
    mov(al,i);


   shr(1,i); //shift bits one position right
   if(@o)then   // if overlow
   stdout.put("overflow");
   endif;

   end cpy;
```

Comment: I have found the answer. If 0 is shifted to the high order bit which previously contained 1 this will change number from negative to positive.

Comment: @Étienne What I think overflow is that number cannot fits to the byte size. So for example if I multiply 120*2 using 8bit integer this will cause overflow. Correct me If Im wrong. I finally know why will number change from negative to positive(if entered negative num) but still have trouble to understand overflow cause for negative numbers (-1...-128)

Answer (score 2):

Signed numbers are represented with their 2's complement in binary, plus a sign bit "on the left". 
The 2's complement of 10 coded on 7 bits is 1110110, and the sign bit value for negative numbers is 1.

```
-10: 1111 0110    
     ^  
     |  
   sign bit
```

Then you shift it to the right (when you right shift zeroes get added to the left):

```
-10 >> 1: 0111 1001  
          ^  
          |  
        sign bit
```

Your sign bit is worth 0 (positive), and 1111011 is 123 in decimal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And any idea about the overflow cause?

Comment: You are misunderstanding something, there is no overflow and everything works as expected in your case :/ What would you expect to be the result?

Comment: Basically im not expecting anything, im just learning bit shifting. So If set overflow flag it become true if negative number shifted right. Am I getting wrong result? Honestly it's really strange for me because i don't see any reason why there should be overflow.

Comment: Are you coding on a microcontroller? How do you check this overflow flag value?